# Помогите разобраться с javassist!

Tags: java

Делаю задание по созданию java-приложения. Стоит задача изменения метода (формулы расчета) без перекомпиляции приложения. После поиска в гугле понял, что можно решить проблему с помощью javassist. Но пока совершенно не получается изменить тело метода. Пока пробую на простом примере. Итак, класс, содержащий единственный метод, который хочу поменять

```
package ru.testScandJavaCafee.service;
public class Helper2 {
public String createList()
{
    System.out.println("++++");
    return "1000";
}
}
```

и класс, из которого меняю метод

```
package ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller;

import javassist.*;
import ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.Helper2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


/**
 * Created by 15 on 06.05.2017.
 */

public class Helper {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, InstantiationException {

    Helper2 helper2 = new Helper2();

    String simple2 = helper2.createList();
    System.out.println(simple2);

    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cc = pool.get("ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.Helper2");

    CtMethod cm = cc.getMethod("createList","()Ljava/lang/String;" );

    cm.setBody( "{ System.out.println(\"----\"); return \"2222 \" ;}" );
    cc.writeFile();


    Method method1 = helper2.getClass().getMethod("createList");
    // Вызвать метод с помощью invoke - передать туда только объект
    String simple = (String)method1.invoke(helper2);
    System.out.println("Simple:" + simple);
}
```

}

После запуска получаю на выходе

```
++++
1000
++++
1000
```

помогите разобраться, почему не выводится измененный метод

Comment: очень сильно намудрил. я так понимаю, ты пытаешься разобраться с наследованием? упрости пример еще сильнее.

Comment: в примере сначала выполняю метод, потом хочу его изменить с помощью javassist, и вызвать его заново, но он выводит всё без изменения. Вроде простой пример, в самом задании нужно изменять в методе большую формулу..